# Junit throughout or redundant test? (basic)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to create some JUnit tests for my methods and I've been told to do it for every single method. I know it's a pitfall for beginners to only do positive tests so how can I test this method more than I already have? Also both of my test methods test the same thing essentially. What would be an example of a negative test here or is that redundant work?

```
public static MemberCont getInstance() {
    if(instance == null)  {
       instance = new MemberCont();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

---

```
@Test
public void getInstance() {
    assertNotNull(memberCo1.getInstance());
    assertEquals(true, memberCo1.getInstance() != null);
}
```

Comment: _"I'm trying to create some Junit tests for my methods and I've been told to do it for every single method."_ this is a bad advice, you should create unittests for every single **behavior**.

Comment: The test you wrote is sufficient.    There should be no other behaviors for the method you are testing - you will return the instance reference.

Comment: your Class under Test implements the _"Java Singelton Pattern"_ which is also usually a misconception.

Comment: Replace the thread-unsafe singleton pattern with a simple enum singleton definition. Also, the two asserts test basically the same thing, so you can remove the latter one. You might do a check if the reference you got returned is the same for two consecutive invocations to guarantee that no new object is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UnitTests should always represent their structure which is 3 parts: *arrange*, *act* and *assert*. Also each desired behavior should have its own test. So your test should look lile this (based on answer of @NicolasFilotto):

```
@Test
public void getInstance__singleCall__NotNull() {
    // no "arrange" possible
    // act
    MemberCont cut = MemberCont.getInstance();
    // assert
    assertNotNull(cut);
}

@Test
public void getInstance__multipleCalls__alwaysTheSameObject() {
    // no "arrange possible
    MemberCont cut1 = MemberCont.getInstance();
    MemberCont cut2 = MemberCont.getInstance();
    assertTrue(cut1 == cut2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You obviously try to implement the [`Singleton Pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) (which is not properly written BTW, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)), so the most important thing to test is that you will always **get the exact same instance**, so your test should rather be something like this:

```
@Test
public void getInstance() {
    assertNotNull(MemberCont.getInstance());
    // Make sure that we get the same instance between 2 subsequent calls
    assertSame(MemberCont.getInstance(), MemberCont.getInstance());
}
```

**NB:** It is a `static` method so you have no need to use an instance to call it, simply call it using the class name directly as I did above.